# Substitution in complex integration

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, substitution

Let $f$ and $\phi$ be continuously differentiable functions on the closed unit disc $D=\{\lambda\in \Bbb C; |\lambda|\leq1\}$ and suppose that there exists $u:[0,2\pi]\to[u_0, u_0+2\pi]$ continuously differentiable such that $$e^{iu(t)}=\phi(e^{it}), t\in[0,2\pi].$$ Let $$A=\int_0^{2\pi}|f(\phi(e^{it}))|^2dt.$$
The author of the book I am reading say that, taking te substitution $u=u(t)$ we conclude that

> $$A=\int_{u_0}^{u_0+2\pi}|f(e^{iu})|^2\frac{1}{|\phi'(e^{it(u)})|}du.$$

I want to conclude this equality, but I didn't undestand why we should put a modulus on that factor... If we differenciate $e^{iu(t)}=\phi(e^{it})$ in $t$ we have $$ie^{iu(t)}\frac{du}{dt}=ie^{it}\phi'(e^{it}), t\in[0,2\pi].$$ If we could take modulus in this equality I could conclude what I want... but why could I do this? The formula for [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_single_variable) is $$\int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(b)}f(x)dx=\int_a^bf(\varphi(t))\varphi'(t)dt.$$

Comment: Can you double-check the desired formula, after making the substitution $u = u(t)$? For example, there should be no reference to $t$ after the substitution. Moreover I find the presence of $\phi(e^{iu})$ surprising as well.

Comment: @JoeyZou I am sorry, just found an error. Thank you and sorry for that. Now the desired formula is correct.

Comment: @JoeyZou the fact is that $$dt=\frac{e^{i(u-t(u))}}{\phi'(e^{it(u)})}du.$$ Why should I put a modulus in it? I think I am understanding something wrong...

Comment: Sorry to keep nitpicking, but the denominator currently says $|\phi(e^{it(u)})|$ -- did you mean a $\phi'$? And what is $t(u)$? There should be no $t$ at all...

Comment: It may also be worth noting that the integral you want is a *real* integral, whereas $\phi:D\rightarrow D$, and $D$ is a subset of the *complex* plane. In order to do substitutions you need to view $D$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and hence $\phi$ as a map from a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$, in which case the change of variables formulas involves a Jacobian (which involves an absolute value).

Comment: @JoeyZou Sorry again, fixed. The term "$t(u)$" is not from me. The book claims that we can obtain that formula... I don't know exactly how can I look into that integral as in $\Bbb R^2$. [Take a look at here.](https://regularize.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/substitution-and-integration-by-parts-for-functions-of-a-complex-variable/) There the "natural formula" (I guess) to use in this occasion is obtained.